# Issues implementing dojox/layout/ExpandoPane

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to implement an ExpandoPane on this web mapping application (using ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17). I'm trying to put an accordian container with two panes onto a collapsable expando pane. Can anyone see why the expandopane is failing (not a collapsible pane, not on the 'right' region, but the upper left corner)?

```
<div id="content"
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
       data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true"
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">

       <div id="rightPane"
           data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ExpandoPane"
           data-dojo-props="region:'right',title:'Widgets',startExpanded:false">

          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
              <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane"
                   data-dojo-props="title:'Légende', selected:true">
                  <div id="legendDiv"></div>
              </div>
              <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
                   data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div id="map"
           data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'"
           style="overflow: hidden;width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
      </div>
      <div id="search"></div>
  </div>
```

Are there particular imports to be done?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include the proper css and imports:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   dojo.require("dojox.layout.ExpandoPane");
   </script>
```